# Finding the extreme points of this set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{m} \in \mathbb R^n$. Prove that each $x_i$ is an extreme point of $D = \text{conv}(\{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m\})$ for $i=1, 2, \dots, m$.

So far, this is my attempt. We write $\text{conv}(\{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m\}):=\{ t_1 x_1 + t_2 x_2 + \dots + t_m x_m: \sum_{k=1}^m t_k = 1, t_k \geq 0, k = 1, 2, \dots m\}$ and let $\overline x$ be an extreme point of D. By definition, $\overline x$ cannot be represented by a convex combination $t_1 x_1 + t_2 x_2 + \dots + t_m x_m$ with $t_k > 0$. It follows that $\overline x \in D$ only if $t_k = 1$ for some $k = 1, 2, \dots, m$. Then, we have $\overline x \in \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m\}$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: This is not true. Take $n=1,m=3$ and $x_k=k$. Then $x_2 = {1 \over 2} (x_1+x_3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think your statement is true. Take the points on the plane $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$ and $(0,0)$. Their convex hull is the square whose vertices are $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(0,0)$ is an interior point, not an extreme point.